# How to detect the session is expired or not in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

My website has a node.js livechat system. By default, the user's session will be expired in 30 seconds unless they call some function to let the server know they are still online, the server will prolong their sessions then.

However, I found that sessions do not get removed after they are expired.when I call function:

```
Hub.prototype.find = function(username, fn) {
    for(var sid in this.sessions) {
        var session = this.sessions[sid],   //session still found even expired...
            sess_username = session.data('username');
        if(sess_username == username) {
            fn(session);
            return;
        }
    }
    fn(false);
};
```

Right now even the session is expired, the "session" can still be found. Why? How can I write in the condition so it won't find any expired sessions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `req.session.destroy()` when you want the session to expire so it will be removed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I want to do this as well, however, the session expires itself, and I don't know how to destroy that in this case. Run a cron?

Comment: There is really no need to delete the sessions, just make sure the session has not expired before accessing it in your app.